# clearing a serial display when newline characters are ignored

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am looking for a way to clear a serial display and write at its beginning using Python and PySerial. The problem is, that the diplay ignores line feeds and carriage returns. It is a 2-line display with 16 characters in each line. Text is always appended at the end, and once, the first line is full, it jumps to the second line like this:

```
+------------------+
|                  |
| Loremipsumdolors |
| itamet__________ |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

*(note, that I replaced spaces with underscores to make understanding easier)*
When the display is full with characters, it is emptied and the rest of the text is written like this:

```
+------------------+
|                  |
| dolorsitamet____ |
| ________________ |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

My code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS1")
ser.write("Some text\r\n")
```

Is there any way to completely empty it and write from the beginning, similiar to a carriage return?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the display's capabilities, there is no common standard. The datasheet of the display should include a list of control codes understood. You might try FF `\f` to clear, but it might very well be some limited ANSI escape sequence. Have y look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). There is hope: it is quite unlikely it is not possible.

For testing, you can leave the Python interpreter in interactive (CLI) mode after the program is run (`python -i <program_file>`). That way you can play with the connection interactively.